# Decide if 4 lengths form a square, rectangle or neither

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of 4 integers, each representing the length of one side of a tetragon in clockwise order (so each number is the length of the side of the right-hand-adjacent-side of the previous one). Integers can be negative or positive or 0.

My idea is that if any of the sides are less than or equal to 0 then it's not a valid tetragon. Then if the lengths of all the sides are equal then it can form a square. Then if lengths of opposing sides are equal then it can form a rectangle, otherwise it's neither.

```
tgons=[[1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,2],[1,2,3,4],[-1,-2,-1,-2],[1,0,1,0]]
squares=0
rects = 0
neithers = 0
for gon in tgons:
    if any(n <= 0 for n in gon): #if any integers <= 0, it's invalid
        neithers+=1
    elif len(set(gon)) == 1: #if all integers are equal, it's a square
        squares+=1
    elif gon[0] == gon[2] and gon[1] == gon[3]: #if both pairs of opposing sides have equal length, it's a rectangle
        rects+=1
    else:
        neithers+=1
print squares,rects,neithers
```

This code apparently fails one out of a few test cases (on a certain website). I've thrown all the test cases I could think of at it and I've not been able to get it to fail so far. Is there really a test case that it fails?

Comment: Depending on the wording of the question, which you should list, then the squares are also rectangles (just very square rectangles). And does the question specifically note negative sides as illegal? I've seen challenges where negative lengths only denotes that instead of going clockwise around the rectangle, they go anti-clockwise (even though your interpretation does sound sensible).

Comment: You shouldn't entangle your tgon identification function and the process of counting shapes in an array of tgons.  that is, make one fn whose input is an array of 4 ints and whose output is the type of shape.  then use a `reduce` function to apply that single identification fn over the array, getting the counts for each shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why do we need a `set` to find a square?
- Why is a square not a subset of rectangle?
- You can do the `any` check in the `gon[0] == gon[2]`.
- Why no filter on length of `gon`? Pentagons aren't squares...
- `gon` is a poor name... do you mean polygon?
- I agree with holroy, -5 makes sense, but 0 does not.

So I would do:

```
for shape in tgons:
    if shape[0] == shape[2] > 0 and shape[1] == shape[3] > 0 and len(shape) == 4:
        if shape[0] == shape[1]:
            squares += 1
        else:
            rects += 1
    else:
        neithers += 1
```

This can also be changed to allow all 2D rects/squares. (not lines.)

```
if shape[0] == shape[2] != 0 and shape[1] == shape[3] != 0 and len(shape) == 4:
```

---

Also follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) a bit more, as then you'll have easier to read code.
You mostly need more spaces:

- Before and after infix operators.
- After but not before commas.

Comment: `shape[0] == shape[2] > 0`? Does it work alike to `a < b < c` where an implicit `and` separate the two parts?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger It works something like that. `2 == 2 > 0` is true, but the following are false: `2 == 3 > 0`, `-2 == -2 > 0` and `-2 == -3 > 0`. I also made a small subclass, just to check, and it gave the numbers as if there was an implicit `and`